# What does "stage-cutch" mean?

Tags: meaning

I would like to ask about the meaning of "stage-cutch" in David Copperfield by Charles Dickens. it appeared in my translation test this afternoon and I didn't find any definition of it.
In my opinion, it may be the misspelling of "stage-coach" made by the character in the story. Is it correct?

Comment: It is indeed a spelling of "stage-coach" which represents Barkis' dialectal pronunciation.

Comment: probably the cause of the phrase 'what the dickens does this mean!'

Comment: I think that's a correct assumption.

Answer (score 1):

As StoneyB points out in a comment above, the cart driver C.P. Barkis—whose cryptic message for Peggotty, "Barkis is willin'" is so baffling to the young David Copperfield—has a strong dialectal pronunciation; and Charles Dickens is not shy about pushing accents and dialect speech to the brink of comic incoherence. Elsewhere in *David Copperfield*, Barkis says things like

> "Chrisen name, or nat'ral name?"

and

> "So she makes all the apple parsties, and doos all the cooking, do she?"

and

> "I'm a friend of your'n."

So it can scarcely be doubted that when he tells David

> "And there [at Yarmouth] I shall take you to the stage-cutch, and the stage-cutch that'll take you to—wherever it is."

he is referring in his C.P. Barkis way to a *stage-coach*.

Comment: It seems incredible to me that anyone would put archaic dialect in a translation test (unless the test were intended to measure how well you handle such dialect, in which case I'd expect some sort of warning).

Comment: That is strange, isn't it? In any case, I don't envy translators the task of mimicking the speech of Dickens characters like Mrs. Gummidge, who says things such as "I'm a lone lorn creetur' myself, and everythink that reminds me of creetur's that ain't lone an lorn, goes contrairy with me."

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the question refers in any way to cutch (a preservative, made from catechu gum boiled in water, used to prolong the life of a sail) or cuitch (empty shells laid on oyster grounds to attract oyster spawn) and conclude we are seeing a misspelling of stagecoach.
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stage-coach#English

Comment: ...or intentional eye-dialect spelling.